# Link inside a collapse

Tags: bootstrap-4

I have a faq page with a set of Q and A. Each Q shows / hides the A with the bootstrap collapse feature.

The various A's have id's for the collapse target, and I also need them to send a user directly to that A.

```
        <li class="question text-muted" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#answer-dragon">
            Do you support Dragon Ball Z?
        </li>
        <li id="answer-dragon" class="answer collapse">
            Yes we do. Our Dragon Ball Z support level is above 9000.
        </li>
```

When I send them there, I would like the A to be expanded.

```
Please see the <a href="faq.html#answer-widget">FAQ</a> about Dragon Ball Z support.
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Use the accordion code https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/collapse/#accordion-example

Comment: @mlegg, that's the same as what I have in the sense that `faq.html#answer-widget` doesn't make that accordian section expand. I think I'm going to have to `$(document).ready(function() {//look for #anchor and expand it});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was simpler than I thought:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var anchor = window.location.hash;
    if(anchor != '')
        $(anchor).collapse('show');
});
```